# Why does LinkedList.indexOf() return -1 if the object is contained in the list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have declared a LinkedList, where Frame is my list item.

```
private LinkedList<Frame> linkedList = new LinkedList<Frame>();
```

I realized that when I test for indexOf -1 is returned even though the list contains the queried item. Documentation states "(...) or -1 if this list does not contain the element.".

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Look at these strange results:

```
linkedList.size() -> 1
linkedList.get(0) -> frame
linkedList.contains(linkedList.get(0)) -> false
linkedList.indexOf(linkedList.get(0)) -> -1
```

Did I overlook anything? Any ideas what's going on?

I am accessing the list from various threads without synchronization. Could this have caused the problem?

--

Log (see below):

```
12-05 20:30:00.101  16446-16461/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              0
12-05 20:30:00.301  16446-16476/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              -1
12-05 20:30:00.856  16446-16461/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              0
12-05 20:30:01.051  16446-16476/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              -1
12-05 20:30:01.601  16446-16461/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              0
12-05 20:30:01.801  16446-16476/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              -1
12-05 20:30:02.356  16446-16461/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              0
12-05 20:30:02.551  16446-16476/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              -1
12-05 20:30:03.101  16446-16461/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              0
12-05 20:30:03.301  16446-16476/cc.closeup I/System.out﹕ **** TEST              -1
```

Comment: How does your `Frame` type implement `equals(Object)`?

Comment: Not at all. Will I need to implement it?

Comment: @OliverHausler yes,then only it will check internally and give you desired result.

Comment: Not really, it will inherit `Object`'s implementation which should work for both `contains` and `indexOf` cases you've shown. Please give us a reproducible example.

Comment: I am working with the Frame class in several places and equals() always worked correctly. There are thousands of LOC involved so it's not easy to cut a reproducible example, but I will try.

Comment: When I isolate it, it does not happen ;-( But I think it comes down to a threading issue. I have attached a log where I show the result of buffer.indexOf(buffer.get(0))). You can see that two threads access the same linkedList (same function call, same statement for logging); and from one thread the result is fine but from the other it is not. The log is attached above.

Comment: Are you properly synchronizing everything? Reads and writes?

Comment: Nop, I haven't done this yet. But I also think this is the problem. Would you think I am fine if I synchronize the list itself? Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>())

Comment: You will also need to put your access to the list in a synchronized block, like: synchronized(linkedList) { //your code }

Comment: I have used **private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Frame> linkedList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Frame>();** and it seems to work fine. - @JoshEdwards will I still need to put access to the list in a synchronized block with that solution? It seems to be working with just the ConcurrentLinkedQueue, but I'd like to make sure it won't break sometime later. [My original unsynchronized list also worked for a while.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at the javadocs for `contains` and `indexOf`.  It states that the methods determine if an element is in the collection by using the `equals` method.

If `contains` and `indexOf` are saying "it isn't there" then the object that is present in the list is a different one to the one you are testing for ... according to the object's implementation of `equals(Object)`.

---

The other possibility is that you are accessing / updating the collection from different threads, and you haven't synchronized properly.  This can lead to one thread seeing a stale or inconsistent version of the list.

> Would you think I am fine if I synchronize the list itself?
>
> ```
>     Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>())
> ```

If you perform all operations via the synchronized list AND you don't use the iterator, then each individual operation will be thread-safe and atomic.  However:

- the iterator of a "synchronized list" is not synchronized, and
- this doesn't help if you need a sequence of operations to be synchronized / performed atomically.

For example:

```
    List<Integer> l =  Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());

    // Make the list visible to other threads ...

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        Integer ii = l.get(i);
        ...
    }
```

While `l.size()` will always give the current size, the size *might* change between the `l.size()` and `l.get(i)` calls, potentially resulting in an exception.

In short ... `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` is NOT a solution for all thread-safety problems involving lists.  You STILL need to think about what you are doing.

Comment: "The other possibility is that you are accessing / updating the collection from different threads, and you haven't synchronized properly. This can lead to one thread seeing a stale or inconsistent version of the list." -> This is exactly what happened.

Comment: Even though this is already answered, here is a link which nicely explains how it may happen that different threads see a different version of the same variable: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html - very good for learning about concurrency as well.